# Difference between two time stamps in PHP

Tags: php, time, mamp, strtotime, maxlength

It seems to me that this should echo 11 hours but it returns 12; what am I missing?

```
$start_time = "06:00";
$end_time = "17:00";
$LOD = date("H:i", ((strtotime($end_time) - strtotime($start_time))));
echo  "Length of day: " . $LOD . " hours";
```

Update: running on my MBPro in a MAMP environment; system time set to 24 hr.

Comment: [It returns 11...](http://www.tehplayground.com/#3onyo85xg)

Comment: I just tried it and it's returning 5 hours, which makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `date` that way doesn't make any sense.

If you want a minimum sense, then you should add `strtotime("00:00")` as your initial time.

`(end - start) + init`

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies here:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore');
echo date('r', strtotime('06:00')); // Mon, 25 May 2015 06:00:00 +0800
date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');
echo date('r', strtotime('06:00')); // Sun, 24 May 2015 06:00:00 -0600
```

Notice how the date has shifted by one day from changing the timezone? This is because the date you supply to `strtotime()` are relative dates, so you need to "ground" it against the start of day:

```
echo date('H:i', strtotime('17:00') - strtotime('06:00') + strtotime('00:00'));
```

Or, use [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime):

```
$t1 = new DateTime('06:00');
$t2 = new DateTime('17:00');
echo $t2->diff($t1)->format('%H:%I');
```

Comment: @Dan You're welcome; I personally prefer to use DateTime to avoid having to think too much about timestamps ;-)

Comment: Always on the ball @Ja͢ck , great answer!

Answer (score 0):

Because it will change to your local server php time.

Try this

```
<?php

    $start_time = "06:30";
    $end_time = "17:50";
    $default_time = "00:00";


    $LOD = date("H:i", (strtotime($default_time)+(strtotime($end_time) - strtotime($start_time))));
    echo  "Length of day: " . $LOD . " hours";

    echo "<br>";

    $diff = strtotime($end_time) - strtotime($start_time);
    $hour = floor($diff / 3600);
    $minute = ($diff % 3600) / 60;
    echo "Length of day: " . $hour . ":" . $minute . " hours";
?>
```